# firefox doesn't fetch #header on style.css (other web browsers are okay)

Tags: css, cross-browser

http://dayforfailure.com is my website.

It looks as expected on Chrome and Safari. But on firefox, header and other elements (like image size) went awry.

I am a noob on cross-browser compatibility issues. Would you help me fix the problem?

Chrome:
[image: Site in Chrome]

Firefox:
[image: Site in Firefox]

Comment: After putting your source code through validator.w3.org, I found a couple issues. I'm not sure if they'll fix your CSS issue, but you should definitely get them fixed either way: You're missing a `</a>` tag at line 229. There is content after the `</html>` tag (ln. 424-431). Your '<body>' tag is currently `<bodyclass="home">' instead of '<body class="home">` (ln. 161). I would recommend taking a look at the validation report and fixing any HTML errors. Debugging your CSS will be a lot easier when you know your HTML is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [Firebug's](https://getfirebug.com/) JavaScript console, you have two errors.

```
ReferenceError: Cufon is not defined
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
```

You also have similar errors on Chrome's developer tool, but Firefox stops working and doesn't load the rest of the resources after encountering an error.

The solution for you is to fix the errors listed in the js console in the Firefox/Firebug developer tool. Then your site will work correctly in each browser.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer and apologies for the late follow-up.

Answer (score 1):

You're having an extra " -character in the line number 67. To be shown correctly, the line should be:

h1 { font-family:"Helvetica Neue","Helvetica", sans-serif; font-size:3 em; color:#000; text-transform:uppercase;}

As Paul mentioned, you're having alot of problems with the HTML file. Just run it through a validator and fix the issues mentioned there :)